# Add custom design time command to WinForms control

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, design-time

I have a custom WinForms control (inherits from control, i.e. without user interface jsut as Timer) to which I want to add a custom command add design time.

This could be similar to the "right click and choose 'Edit Items...'" of a menu.

Is this posisble? How?

Also, could you recommend some general reading (online) about improving the design time experience of custom controls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First here is a link to the relevant MSDN doco on the subject

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171567(VS.80).aspx

and more specifically

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.menucommand(VS.80).aspx

As for a book that covers this, [Chris Sells Winforms book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321267966) is probably the best, however to be honest, I don't think that any of the books out there (on-line or otherwise) cover design time features in the sort of depth that I personally would like.

Comment: I'm curious to know what depth of design time knowledge do you want that's not in Chris's book? About the only thing he didn't cover was writing your own designer...

Comment: you nailed it :-) 

There is precious little info anywhere about how to write your own designer, "one with the lot". I'm not picking on Chris by the way, he covers more than anyone else, and his book is great.

Comment: I'm still struggling, but it's the start I was loking for - thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Another good link is

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163758.aspx

The article covers most of what is mentioned on this subject in Chris Sells' book, but the book is still worth buying.